# Sorting JSON (by specific element) alphabetically

Tags: javascript, json, sorting

I have some JSON that is formatted like:

```
places =[
     {
      "city":"Los Angeles",
      "country":"USA",
     },
     {
      "city":"Boston",
      "country":"USA",
     },
     {
      "city":"Chicago",
      "country":"USA",
     },
]
```

et cetera...

I am trying to sort this alphabetically **BY CITY**  and am having trouble doing so. I believe the root of my issue seems to be determining the order of the characters (versus numbers). I've tried a simple:

```
    places.sort(function(a,b) {
     return(a.city) - (b.customInfo.city);
    });
```

yet, this subtraction doesnt know what to do. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no generic "compare" function in JavaScript to return a suitable value for sort(). I'd write a compareStrings function that uses comparison operators and then use it in the sort function.

```
function compareStrings(a, b) {
  // Assuming you want case-insensitive comparison
  a = a.toLowerCase();
  b = b.toLowerCase();

  return (a < b) ? -1 : (a > b) ? 1 : 0;
}

places.sort(function(a, b) {
  return compareStrings(a.city, b.city);
})
```

Comment: holy crap, Matti, I owe you a beer. Why does the comparison between a<b work? Does that know to check the characters for order?

Comment: The comparison works because `<` and friends are defined to use lexicographical ordering for strings. Internally it checks each matching character and when it finds two different Unicode values, it returns, which results in "dictionary" ordering. This is also why I added toLowerCase() calls just in case, because the comparison itself compares codepoint values only. It doesn't check for case.

Answer (score 16):

Matti's solution is correct, but you can write it more simply. You don't need the extra function call; you can put the logic directly in the `sort` callback.

For case-insensitive sorting:

```
places.sort( function( a, b ) {
    a = a.city.toLowerCase();
    b = b.city.toLowerCase();

    return a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0;
});
```

For case-sensitive sorting:

```
places.sort( function( a, b ) {
    return a.city < b.city ? -1 : a.city > b.city ? 1 : 0;
});
```

Comment: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/764/how-to-sort-alphabetically-an-array-of-objects-by-key-in-javascript. This worked for me

Answer (score 1):

In the context of sorting cities, especially if we're fetching them from an API or any other source where duplicate city names aren't expected, we can simplify the sorting function for better readability.

```
places.sort(function (a, b) {
     return a.city < b.city ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Here we're essentially saying: If **a.city** comes before **b.city** alphabetically then place **a** before **b** in the sorted array. Otherwise, place **b** before **a**.

**Even in the unlikely scenario where duplicate city names exist, this function will still work**