# sort JSON object alphabeticly

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Im trying to use underscore.js to sort my JSON object, however it doesn't seem to sort it alphabeticly when I sort by companyName?

As you can see with this code, the third object in data.adverts has doesnt start with the letter D ?

Code looks like:

```
var sortedDesc = _.sortBy(data.adverts, 'companyName');

$.each(sortedDesc, function () {
   Doing my stuff here.....
});
```

The object looks like:

```
data({
"title" : "Krak firma API",
"query" : "http://api.eniro.com/cs/search/basic?geo_area=danmark&country=dk&search_word=DIS&version=1.1.3&callback=jQuery22003420392591506243_1456226871368",
"totalHits" : 44,
"totalCount" : 44,
"startIndex" : 1,
"itemsPerPage" : 25,
"adverts" : [{
        "eniroId" : "66139761",
        "companyInfo" : {
            "companyName" : "Dansk Industri Service A/S",
            "orgNumber" : "20250844",
            "cvrPNumber" : "1004202979",
            "companyText" : null
        },
        "address" : {
            "streetName" : "Generatorvej 17",
            "postCode" : "2860",
            "postArea" : "Søborg",
            "postBox" : null
        },
        "location" : {
            "coordinates" : [{
                    "longitude" : 12.465702,
                    "latitude" : 55.729974
                }, {
                    "use" : "route",
                    "longitude" : 12.465662,
                    "latitude" : 55.730202
                }
            ]
        },
        "phoneNumbers" : [{
                "type" : "std",
                "phoneNumber" : "70 20 70 15",
                "label" : null
            }
        ],
        "companyReviews" : "http://www.dethitter.dk/brugeranmeldelse/f/66139761/dis",
        "homepage" : "http://api.eniro.com/proxy/homepage/uANwPf5aVK2cGM31dAhxnP94Fw6wLDJmjGFCQRGYZgO51Qs6_d_2i9h4MLaWRmsw_87mP_j3IjX1e2t2Hx6_yQ==",
        "facebook" : null,
        "infoPageLink" : "http://www.krak.dk/f/dansk-industri-service-as:66139761?search_word=DIS"
    }, {
        "eniroId" : "66295511",
        "companyInfo" : {
            "companyName" : "Diss",
            "orgNumber" : "30924606",
            "cvrPNumber" : "1013726465",
            "companyText" : null
        },
        "address" : {
            "coName" : "Rikke Søndermølle",
            "streetName" : "Hovangsvej 71",
            "postCode" : "9500",
            "postArea" : "Hobro",
            "postBox" : null
        },
        "location" : {
            "coordinates" : [{
                    "longitude" : 9.786483,
                    "latitude" : 56.649997
                }, {
                    "use" : "route",
                    "longitude" : 9.786596,
                    "latitude" : 56.650012
                }
            ]
        },
        "phoneNumbers" : [{
                "type" : "std",
                "phoneNumber" : "58 52 62 61",
                "label" : null
            }
        ],
        "companyReviews" : "http://www.dethitter.dk/brugeranmeldelse/f/66295511/dis",
        "homepage" : null,
        "facebook" : null,
        "infoPageLink" : "http://www.krak.dk/f/diss:66295511?search_word=DIS"
    }, {
        "eniroId" : "66741314",
        "companyInfo" : {
            "companyName" : "Moster Di's Grill og Kaffevogn",
            "orgNumber" : "21651605",
            "cvrPNumber" : "1017404705",
            "companyText" : null
        },
        "address" : {
            "streetName" : "Hedelandsvej 14",
            "postCode" : "7400",
            "postArea" : "Herning",
            "postBox" : null
        },
        "location" : {
            "coordinates" : [{
                    "longitude" : 8.935914,
                    "latitude" : 56.127568
                }, {
                    "use" : "route",
                    "longitude" : 8.93635,
                    "latitude" : 56.127463
                }
            ]
        },
        "phoneNumbers" : [{
                "type" : "std",
                "phoneNumber" : "97 42 04 20",
                "label" : null
            }
        ],
        "companyReviews" : "http://www.dethitter.dk/brugeranmeldelse/f/66741314/dis",
        "homepage" : null,
        "facebook" : null,
        "infoPageLink" : "http://www.krak.dk/f/moster-dis-grill-og-kaffevogn:66741314?search_word=DIS"
    }, {
        "eniroId" : "122768415",
        "companyInfo" : {
            "companyName" : "Dis Byg ApS",
            "orgNumber" : "37167304",
            "cvrPNumber" : "1020824162",
            "companyText" : null
        },
        "address" : {
            "streetName" : "Ved Banen 8",
            "postCode" : "7100",
            "postArea" : "Vejle",
            "postBox" : null
        },
        "location" : {
            "coordinates" : [{
                    "longitude" : 9.553109,
                    "latitude" : 55.698735
                }, {
                    "use" : "route",
                    "longitude" : 9.553159,
                    "latitude" : 55.698833
                }
            ]
        },
        "phoneNumbers" : [],
        "companyReviews" : "http://www.dethitter.dk/brugeranmeldelse/f/122768415/dis",
        "homepage" : null,
        "facebook" : null,
        "infoPageLink" : "http://www.krak.dk/f/dis-byg-aps:122768415?search_word=DIS"
    }, {
        "eniroId" : "121468337",
        "companyInfo" : {
            "companyName" : "Dis",
            "orgNumber" : null,
            "cvrPNumber" : null,
            "companyText" : null
        },
        "address" : {
            "streetName" : "Studiestræde 21 A",
            "postCode" : "1455",
            "postArea" : "København K",
            "postBox" : null
        },
        "location" : {
            "coordinates" : [{
                    "longitude" : 12.5697907,
                    "latitude" : 55.6784752
                }, {
                    "use" : "route",
                    "longitude" : 12.5697907,
                    "latitude" : 55.6784752
                }
            ]
        },
        "phoneNumbers" : [{
                "type" : "std",
                "phoneNumber" : "33 12 00 00",
                "label" : null
            }
        ],
        "companyReviews" : "http://www.dethitter.dk/brugeranmeldelse/f/121468337/dis",
        "homepage" : null,
        "facebook" : null,
        "infoPageLink" : "http://www.krak.dk/f/dis:121468337?search_word=DIS"
    }, {
        "eniroId" : "108935200",
        "companyInfo" : {
            "companyName" : "Seapay Dis ApS",
            "orgNumber" : "36054506",
            "cvrPNumber" : "1019585685",
            "companyText" : null
        },
        "address" : {
            "streetName" : "Ivar Bentsens Vej 12",
            "postCode" : "4300",
            "postArea" : "Holbæk",
            "postBox" : null
        },
        "location" : {
            "coordinates" : [{
                    "longitude" : 11.758894,
                    "latitude" : 55.717305
                }, {
                    "use" : "route",
                    "longitude" : 11.758669,
                    "latitude" : 55.717311
                }
            ]
        },
        "phoneNumbers" : [],
        "companyReviews" : "http://www.dethitter.dk/brugeranmeldelse/f/108935200/dis",
        "homepage" : null,
        "facebook" : null,
        "infoPageLink" : "http://www.krak.dk/f/seapay-dis-aps:108935200?search_word=DIS"
    }, {
        "eniroId" : "66303436",
        "companyInfo" : {
            "companyName" : "Dis-Faxe",
            "orgNumber" : "33686587",
            "cvrPNumber" : "1016954493",
            "companyText" : null
        },
        "address" : {
            "coName" : "Gitte Willumsen Berg",
            "streetName" : "Terslev Bygade 7",
            "postCode" : "4690",
            "postArea" : "Haslev",
            "postBox" : null
        },
        "location" : {
            "coordinates" : [{
                    "longitude" : 11.969888,
                    "latitude" : 55.374341
                }, {
                    "use" : "route",
                    "longitude" : 11.970108,
                    "latitude" : 55.374433
                }
            ]
        },
        "phoneNumbers" : [{
                "type" : "std",
                "phoneNumber" : "30 29 98 77",
                "label" : null
            }
        ],
        "companyReviews" : "http://www.dethitter.dk/brugeranmeldelse/f/66303436/dis",
        "homepage" : null,
        "facebook" : null,
        "infoPageLink" : "http://www.krak.dk/f/dis-faxe:66303436?search_word=DIS"
    }, {
        "eniroId" : "68809471",
        "companyInfo" : {
            "companyName" : "Dis Bygge Og Ejendomsadministration",
            "orgNumber" : null,
            "cvrPNumber" : null,
            "companyText" : null
        },
        "address" : {
            "streetName" : "Tuborg Boulevard 12, 1. sal.",
            "postCode" : "2900",
            "postArea" : "Hellerup",
            "postBox" : null
        },
        "location" : {
            "coordinates" : [{
                    "longitude" : 12.5807377,
                    "latitude" : 55.7271613
                }, {
                    "use" : "route",
                    "longitude" : 12.5807377,
                    "latitude" : 55.7271613
                }
            ]
        },
        "phoneNumbers" : [{
                "type" : "std",
                "phoneNumber" : "24 45 71 74",
                "label" : null
            }
        ],
        "companyReviews" : "http://www.dethitter.dk/brugeranmeldelse/f/68809471/dis",
        "homepage" : null,
        "facebook" : null,
        "infoPageLink" : "http://www.krak.dk/f/dis-bygge-og-ejendomsadministration:68809471?search_word=DIS"
    }, {
        "eniroId" : "93544746",
        "companyInfo" : {
            "companyName" : "Dis Center ApS",
            "orgNumber" : "35473009",
            "cvrPNumber" : "1018749374",
            "companyText" : null
        },
        "address" : {
            "streetName" : "Hammershøj 38",
            "postCode" : "9460",
            "postArea" : "Brovst",
            "postBox" : null
        },
        "location" : {
            "coordinates" : [{
                    "longitude" : 9.596158,
                    "latitude" : 57.05976
                }, {
                    "use" : "route",
                    "longitude" : 9.596163,
                    "latitude" : 57.059895
                }
            ]
        },
        "phoneNumbers" : [],
        "companyReviews" : "http://www.dethitter.dk/brugeranmeldelse/f/93544746/dis",
        "homepage" : null,
        "facebook" : null,
        "infoPageLink" : "http://www.krak.dk/f/dis-center-aps:93544746?search_word=DIS"
    }, {
        "eniroId" : "66949810",
        "companyInfo" : {
            "companyName" : "Dis-Danmark",
            "orgNumber" : "16917338",
            "cvrPNumber" : "1005846555",
            "companyText" : null
        },
        "address" : {
            "coName" : "Jan Amnitzbøl Krusell",
            "streetName" : "Frøkærparken 116",
            "postCode" : "8320",
            "postArea" : "Mårslet",
            "postBox" : null
        },
        "location" : {
            "coordinates" : [{
                    "longitude" : 10.152582,
                    "latitude" : 56.07644
                }, {
                    "use" : "route",
                    "longitude" : 10.152397,
                    "latitude" : 56.076574
                }
            ]
        },
        "phoneNumbers" : [{
                "type" : "std",
                "phoneNumber" : "24 63 62 69",
                "label" : null
            }
        ],
        "companyReviews" : "http://www.dethitter.dk/brugeranmeldelse/f/66949810/dis",
        "homepage" : "http://api.eniro.com/proxy/homepage/uANwPf5aVK26f2J7KyRZqimid0oj_3qIjQ0XbJhXGfpb4h41yM5odSv_D17GURWQlMNOi53PltI=",
        "facebook" : null,
        "infoPageLink" : "http://www.krak.dk/f/dis-danmark:66949810?search_word=DIS"
    }, {
        "eniroId" : "123661747",
        "companyInfo" : {
            "companyName" : "Dis Group Holding A/S",
            "orgNumber" : "37226963",
            "cvrPNumber" : "1020895019",
            "companyText" : null
        },
        "address" : {
            "streetName" : "Ørstedsvej 10",
            "postCode" : "8660",
            "postArea" : "Skanderborg",
            "postBox" : null
        },
        "location" : {
            "coordinates" : [{
                    "longitude" : 9.980758,
                    "latitude" : 56.069991
                }, {
                    "use" : "route",
                    "longitude" : 9.9793,
                    "latitude" : 56.070543
                }
            ]
        },
        "phoneNumbers" : [],
        "companyReviews" : "http://www.dethitter.dk/brugeranmeldelse/f/123661747/dis",
        "homepage" : null,
        "facebook" : null,
        "infoPageLink" : "http://www.krak.dk/f/dis-group-holding-as:123661747?search_word=DIS"
    }, {
        "eniroId" : "109604576",
        "companyInfo" : {
            "companyName" : "Fonden Dis",
            "orgNumber" : null,
            "cvrPNumber" : null,
            "companyText" : null
        },
        "address" : {
            "streetName" : "Holmbladsgade 70 B",
            "postCode" : "2300",
            "postArea" : "København S",
            "postBox" : null
        },
        "location" : {
            "coordinates" : [{
                    "longitude" : 12.6120585,
                    "latitude" : 55.6648985
                }, {
                    "use" : "route",
                    "longitude" : 12.6120585,
                    "latitude" : 55.6648985
                }
            ]
        },
        "phoneNumbers" : [{
                "type" : "std",
                "phoneNumber" : "32 84 11 17",
                "label" : null
            }
        ],
        "companyReviews" : "http://www.dethitter.dk/brugeranmeldelse/f/109604576/dis",
        "homepage" : null,
        "facebook" : null,
        "infoPageLink" : "http://www.krak.dk/f/fonden-dis:109604576?search_word=DIS"
    }, {
        "eniroId" : "66902798",
        "companyInfo" : {
            "companyName" : "Dis Holding ApS",
            "orgNumber" : "29180407",
            "cvrPNumber" : "1011836085",
            "companyText" : null
        },
        "address" : {
            "coName" : "Rikke Søndermølle",
            "streetName" : "Hovangsvej 71",
            "postCode" : "9500",
            "postArea" : "Hobro",
            "postBox" : null
        },
        "location" : {
            "coordinates" : [{
                    "longitude" : 9.786483,
                    "latitude" : 56.649997
                }, {
                    "use" : "route",
                    "longitude" : 9.786596,
                    "latitude" : 56.650012
                }
            ]
        },
        "phoneNumbers" : [{
                "type" : "std",
                "phoneNumber" : "22 99 66 96",
                "label" : null
            }, {
                "type" : "custom",
                "phoneNumber" : "40 88 83 48",
                "label" : "Mobil"
            }
        ],
        "companyReviews" : "http://www.dethitter.dk/brugeranmeldelse/f/66902798/dis",
        "homepage" : null,
        "facebook" : null,
        "infoPageLink" : "http://www.krak.dk/f/dis-holding-aps:66902798?search_word=DIS"
    }, {
        "eniroId" : "68536140",
        "companyInfo" : {
            "companyName" : "Danish Ins.for Study Abroad Dis",
            "orgNumber" : null,
            "cvrPNumber" : null,
            "companyText" : null
        },
        "address" : {
            "streetName" : "Ctr By ",
            "postCode" : "1199",
            "postArea" : "Kh K",
            "postBox" : null
        },
        "location" : {
            "coordinates" : [{
                    "longitude" : null,
                    "latitude" : null
                }, {
                    "use" : "route",
                    "longitude" : null,
                    "latitude" : null
                }
            ]
        },
        "phoneNumbers" : [{
                "type" : "std",
                "phoneNumber" : "33 11 51 91",
                "label" : null
            }
        ],
        "companyReviews" : "http://www.dethitter.dk/brugeranmeldelse/f/68536140/dis",
        "homepage" : null,
        "facebook" : null,
        "infoPageLink" : "http://www.krak.dk/f/danish-insfor-study-abroad-dis:68536140?search_word=DIS"
    }, {
        "eniroId" : "112589612",
        "companyInfo" : {
            "companyName" : "Fonden Dis",
            "orgNumber" : null,
            "cvrPNumber" : null,
            "companyText" : null
        },
        "address" : {
            "streetName" : "Peder Skrams Gade 23, 1. sal.",
            "postCode" : "1054",
            "postArea" : "København K",
            "postBox" : null
        },
        "location" : {
            "coordinates" : [{
                    "longitude" : 12.5895666,
                    "latitude" : 55.6773222
                }, {
                    "use" : "route",
                    "longitude" : 12.5895666,
                    "latitude" : 55.6773222
                }
            ]
        },
        "phoneNumbers" : [{
                "type" : "std",
                "phoneNumber" : "33 15 05 30",
                "label" : null
            }
        ],
        "companyReviews" : "http://www.dethitter.dk/brugeranmeldelse/f/112589612/dis",
        "homepage" : null,
        "facebook" : null,
        "infoPageLink" : "http://www.krak.dk/f/fonden-dis:112589612?search_word=DIS"
    }, {
        "eniroId" : "108478586",
        "companyInfo" : {
            "companyName" : "Fonden Dis",
            "orgNumber" : null,
            "cvrPNumber" : null,
            "companyText" : null
        },
        "address" : {
            "streetName" : "Ravnsborggade 11",
            "postCode" : "2200",
            "postArea" : "København N",
            "postBox" : null
        },
        "location" : {
            "coordinates" : [{
                    "longitude" : 12.5618939,
                    "latitude" : 55.688666
                }, {
                    "use" : "route",
                    "longitude" : 12.5618939,
                    "latitude" : 55.688666
                }
            ]
        },
        "phoneNumbers" : [{
                "type" : "std",
                "phoneNumber" : "35 36 65 05",
                "label" : null
            }
        ],
        "companyReviews" : "http://www.dethitter.dk/brugeranmeldelse/f/108478586/dis",
        "homepage" : null,
        "facebook" : null,
        "infoPageLink" : "http://www.krak.dk/f/fonden-dis:108478586?search_word=DIS"
    }, {
        "eniroId" : "67198842",
        "companyInfo" : {
            "companyName" : "Fabriksarbejder Klubben Abb Dis- Tribution",
            "orgNumber" : "15624299",
            "cvrPNumber" : "1005745320",
            "companyText" : null
        },
        "address" : {
            "streetName" : "Ligustervænget 9",
            "postCode" : "7000",
            "postArea" : "Fredericia",
            "postBox" : null
        },
        "location" : {
            "coordinates" : [{
                    "longitude" : 9.749819,
                    "latitude" : 55.610781
                }, {
                    "use" : "route",
                    "longitude" : 9.749936,
                    "latitude" : 55.610541
                }
            ]
        },
        "phoneNumbers" : [],
        "companyReviews" : "http://www.dethitter.dk/brugeranmeldelse/f/67198842/dis",
        "homepage" : null,
        "facebook" : null,
        "infoPageLink" : "http://www.krak.dk/f/fabriksarbejder-klubben-abb-dis-tribution:67198842?search_word=DIS"
    }, {
        "eniroId" : "104892983",
        "companyInfo" : {
            "companyName" : "Dis-Skive",
            "orgNumber" : "35575154",
            "cvrPNumber" : "1019219093",
            "companyText" : null
        },
        "address" : {
            "coName" : "Lone Hjorth Nielsen",
            "streetName" : "Brombærvej 10",
            "postCode" : "7800",
            "postArea" : "Skive",
            "postBox" : null
        },
        "location" : {
            "coordinates" : [{
                    "longitude" : 9.027915,
                    "latitude" : 56.586359
                }, {
                    "use" : "route",
                    "longitude" : 9.027838,
                    "latitude" : 56.586196
                }
            ]
        },
        "phoneNumbers" : [],
        "companyReviews" : "http://www.dethitter.dk/brugeranmeldelse/f/104892983/dis",
        "homepage" : null,
        "facebook" : null,
        "infoPageLink" : "http://www.krak.dk/f/dis-skive:104892983?search_word=DIS"
    }, {
        "eniroId" : "66957596",
        "companyInfo" : {
            "companyName" : "Dis Udlejning ApS",
            "orgNumber" : "32143237",
            "cvrPNumber" : "1015238832",
            "companyText" : null
        },
        "address" : {
            "streetName" : "Generatorvej 17",
            "postCode" : "2860",
            "postArea" : "Søborg",
            "postBox" : null
        },
        "location" : {
            "coordinates" : [{
                    "longitude" : 12.465702,
                    "latitude" : 55.729974
                }, {
                    "use" : "route",
                    "longitude" : 12.465662,
                    "latitude" : 55.730202
                }
            ]
        },
        "phoneNumbers" : [{
                "type" : "std",
                "phoneNumber" : "70 20 70 15",
                "label" : null
            }
        ],
        "companyReviews" : "http://www.dethitter.dk/brugeranmeldelse/f/66957596/dis",
        "homepage" : null,
        "facebook" : null,
        "infoPageLink" : "http://www.krak.dk/f/dis-udlejning-aps:66957596?search_word=DIS"
    }, {
        "eniroId" : "67034343",
        "companyInfo" : {
            "companyName" : "DI's Risk Management Forening",
            "orgNumber" : "33336047",
            "cvrPNumber" : "1016630620",
            "companyText" : null
        },
        "address" : {
            "coName" : "DI, 1787 v",
            "streetName" : "H.C. Andersens Boulevard 18",
            "postCode" : "1553",
            "postArea" : "København V",
            "postBox" : null
        },
        "location" : {
            "coordinates" : [{
                    "longitude" : 12.568025,
                    "latitude" : 55.675344
                }, {
                    "use" : "route",
                    "longitude" : 12.568243,
                    "latitude" : 55.675492
                }
            ]
        },
        "phoneNumbers" : [{
                "type" : "std",
                "phoneNumber" : "33 77 33 77",
                "label" : null
            }
        ],
        "companyReviews" : "http://www.dethitter.dk/brugeranmeldelse/f/67034343/dis",
        "homepage" : null,
        "facebook" : null,
        "infoPageLink" : "http://www.krak.dk/f/dis-risk-management-forening:67034343?search_word=DIS"
    }, {
        "eniroId" : "66269242",
        "companyInfo" : {
            "companyName" : "DIs Personaleforening, DIP",
            "orgNumber" : "26832039",
            "cvrPNumber" : "1009390797",
            "companyText" : null
        },
        "address" : {
            "coName" : "DI, 1787 v",
            "streetName" : "H.C. Andersens Boulevard 18",
            "postCode" : "1553",
            "postArea" : "København V",
            "postBox" : null
        },
        "location" : {
            "coordinates" : [{
                    "longitude" : 12.568025,
                    "latitude" : 55.675344
                }, {
                    "use" : "route",
                    "longitude" : 12.568243,
                    "latitude" : 55.675492
                }
            ]
        },
        "phoneNumbers" : [{
                "type" : "std",
                "phoneNumber" : "40 19 80 90",
                "label" : null
            }, {
                "type" : "custom",
                "phoneNumber" : "30 59 05 02",
                "label" : "Mobil"
            }
        ],
        "companyReviews" : "http://www.dethitter.dk/brugeranmeldelse/f/66269242/dis",
        "homepage" : null,
        "facebook" : null,
        "infoPageLink" : "http://www.krak.dk/f/dis-personaleforening-dip:66269242?search_word=DIS"
    }, {
        "eniroId" : "66180758",
        "companyInfo" : {
            "companyName" : "DIS-Næstved",
            "orgNumber" : "34762996",
            "cvrPNumber" : "1018256270",
            "companyText" : null
        },
        "address" : {
            "coName" : "Per Hartvig-Olsen",
            "streetName" : "Tornemarksvej 38",
            "postCode" : "4700",
            "postArea" : "Næstved",
            "postBox" : null
        },
        "location" : {
            "coordinates" : [{
                    "longitude" : 11.561402,
                    "latitude" : 55.239048
                }, {
                    "use" : "route",
                    "longitude" : 11.560598,
                    "latitude" : 55.238628
                }
            ]
        },
        "phoneNumbers" : [],
        "companyReviews" : "http://www.dethitter.dk/brugeranmeldelse/f/66180758/dis",
        "homepage" : null,
        "facebook" : null,
        "infoPageLink" : "http://www.krak.dk/f/dis-næstved:66180758?search_word=DIS"
    }, {
        "eniroId" : "102638245",
        "companyInfo" : {
            "companyName" : "Dis-Sydfyn",
            "orgNumber" : "35548130",
            "cvrPNumber" : "1019012014",
            "companyText" : null
        },
        "address" : {
            "coName" : "Nani Krejsing",
            "streetName" : "Kogtvedvej 76",
            "postCode" : "5700",
            "postArea" : "Svendborg",
            "postBox" : null
        },
        "location" : {
            "coordinates" : [{
                    "longitude" : 10.583639,
                    "latitude" : 55.048368
                }, {
                    "use" : "route",
                    "longitude" : 10.583852,
                    "latitude" : 55.048192
                }
            ]
        },
        "phoneNumbers" : [{
                "type" : "std",
                "phoneNumber" : "65 31 60 31",
                "label" : null
            }
        ],
        "companyReviews" : "http://www.dethitter.dk/brugeranmeldelse/f/102638245/dis",
        "homepage" : null,
        "facebook" : null,
        "infoPageLink" : "http://www.krak.dk/f/dis-sydfyn:102638245?search_word=DIS"
    }, {
        "eniroId" : "103192650",
        "companyInfo" : {
            "companyName" : "Dis-Kongeaaen",
            "orgNumber" : "35585036",
            "cvrPNumber" : "1019047985",
            "companyText" : null
        },
        "address" : {
            "coName" : "Jens christian Andersen",
            "streetName" : "Toftager 16",
            "postCode" : "6660",
            "postArea" : "Lintrup",
            "postBox" : null
        },
        "location" : {
            "coordinates" : [{
                    "longitude" : 8.971892,
                    "latitude" : 55.409949
                }, {
                    "use" : "route",
                    "longitude" : 8.971726,
                    "latitude" : 55.40997
                }
            ]
        },
        "phoneNumbers" : [{
                "type" : "std",
                "phoneNumber" : "74 85 54 23",
                "label" : null
            }
        ],
        "companyReviews" : "http://www.dethitter.dk/brugeranmeldelse/f/103192650/dis",
        "homepage" : null,
        "facebook" : null,
        "infoPageLink" : "http://www.krak.dk/f/dis-kongeaaen:103192650?search_word=DIS"
    }, {
        "eniroId" : "67016411",
        "companyInfo" : {
            "companyName" : "DIS København Nord",
            "orgNumber" : "31661811",
            "cvrPNumber" : "1014736502",
            "companyText" : null
        },
        "address" : {
            "coName" : "Ann Christensen",
            "streetName" : "Ellestien 1",
            "postCode" : "2880",
            "postArea" : "Bagsværd",
            "postBox" : null
        },
        "location" : {
            "coordinates" : [{
                    "longitude" : 12.45442,
                    "latitude" : 55.768364
                }, {
                    "use" : "route",
                    "longitude" : 12.454607,
                    "latitude" : 55.768437
                }
            ]
        },
        "phoneNumbers" : [{
                "type" : "std",
                "phoneNumber" : "22 58 86 46",
                "label" : null
            }
        ],
        "companyReviews" : "http://www.dethitter.dk/brugeranmeldelse/f/67016411/dis",
        "homepage" : null,
        "facebook" : null,
        "infoPageLink" : "http://www.krak.dk/f/dis-københavn-nord:67016411?search_word=DIS"
    }
]
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `companyName` is a property inside `companyInfo` so you should try something like this:

```
var sortedDesc = _.sortBy(data.adverts, function(a){ return a.companyInfo.companyName; });
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no generic "compare" function in JavaScript to return a suitable value for sort(). I'd write a compareStrings function that uses comparison operators and then use it in the sort function.

```
function compareStrings(a, b) {
  // Assuming you want case-insensitive comparison
  a = a.toLowerCase();
  b = b.toLowerCase();

  return (a < b) ? -1 : (a > b) ? 1 : 0;
}

places.sort(function(a, b) {
  return compareStrings(a.city, b.city);
})
```

more detail visit here. [Sorting JSON (by specific element) alphabetically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19259233/sorting-json-by-specific-element-alphabetically)