# How can i sort array using AngularJs or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, sorting

I wanted to sort and display array in alphabetical order once user make selection or when we render data from backend i want to display `fullName` in alphabetical order. `$scope.selecedControlOwner` is `ng-click` event handler once user select owners from the modal window and click Ok `ng-click` event trigger and display values on parent window Now here i want to trigger sorting.

`$scope.controlOwnerObj.workerName` is ng-model that is binding the values to parent window.

Is there any solution using AngularJs or native Javascript ?

ctrl.js

```
$scope.selectedControlOwner = function() {
      $scope.controlOwnerObj.workerName= $scope.selectedOwners.map(function (owner) { return owner.fullName; }).join(';');
     };


    $scope.selectedOwners = [{
            "workerKey": 46958,
            "fullName": ,"Kumari, Swapna"
        }, {
            "workerKey": 746,
            "fullName": "Mike Piero",
        }, {
            "workerKey": 150918,
            "fullName": "A J, Jyothish",
        }],
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19259233/sorting-json-by-specific-element-alphabetically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting an array of JavaScript objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use javascript built-in [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function

```
$scope.selectedOwners = [{
            "workerKey": 46958,
            "fullName": ,"Kumari, Swapna"
        }, {
            "workerKey": 746,
            "fullName": "Mike Piero",
        }, {
            "workerKey": 150918,
            "fullName": "A J, Jyothish",
        }],
$scope.selectedOwners.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.fullName.localeCompare(b.fullName);
});
```

Comment: Problem here is even array sorted i am assigning `$scope.controlOwnerObj.workerName` to the ng-model , do we need to something with that property little confuse here

Comment: @hussain if you want to have sorted string of owners name you must sort your array before `map`, like this `.sort(function(a, b) {return a.fullName.localeCompare(b.fullName);}).map(function (owner) { return owner.fullName; }).join(';');`

Answer (score 1):

I will be using only pure javascript, since you gave us that as an option

This sorts them from low to height

```
  var arr = [12, 213, 3, 121, 44, 12];
    arr.sort(function (x, y) {
        return x > y;
    })
```

It doesn't returns a new array.

Result: [3, 12, 12, 44, 121, 213]

this sorts them from height to low

```
    arr.sort(function (x, y) {
        return x < y;
    })
```

Result [213, 121, 44, 12, 12, 3]

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use angularjs orderby..

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy