# Sort and group objects alphabetically by first letter Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting, collections

Im trying to create a collection like this in order to use in a react component:

```
let data = [
    { 
        group : 'A', 
        children : [
            { name : 'Animals', id : 22 },
            ...
        ]
    },
    { 
        group : 'B', children : [
            { name : 'Batteries', id : 7},
            { name : 'Baggage', id : 12 },
            ...
        ]
    },
    { 
        group : 'C', children : [
            { name : 'Cake', id : 7},
            ...
        ]
    },
]
```

I've already sort my data like this :

```
let rawData = [
    { name : 'Animals', id : 10},
    { name : 'Batteries', id : 7},
    { name : 'Baggage', id : 12 },
    { name : 'Cake', id : 7},
    ...
]
```

Also I used this [sorting method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43750568/sorting-json-alphabetically-by-first-letter) but the problem is, it's returning an Object with `A`, `B`, `C` keys with children as values. But I have to turn it into array like above in order to use that.

Here is what i've tried so far :

```
let data = rawData.reduce(function(prevVal, newVal){   
    char = newVal.name[0].toUpperCase();
    return { group: char, children :{name : newVal.name, id : newVal.id}};
},[])
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can create object with `reduce` and then use `Object.values` on that object.

```js
let rawData = [
  { name : 'Animals', id : 10},
  { name : 'Batteries', id : 7},
  { name : 'Baggage', id : 12 },
  { name : 'Cake', id : 7},
]

let data = rawData.reduce((r, e) => {
  // get first letter of name of current element
  let group = e.name[0];
  // if there is no property in accumulator with this letter create it
  if(!r[group]) r[group] = {group, children: [e]}
  // if there is push current element to children array for that letter
  else r[group].children.push(e);
  // return accumulator
  return r;
}, {})

// since data at this point is an object, to get array of values
// we use Object.values method
let result = Object.values(data)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Hi @NenadVracar, can you explain this a little more? Thanks in advance...

Comment: @Gerben den Boer Updated the answer.

Comment: @NenadVracar I think this does not sort the object alphabetically? or am i missing something

Comment: Firstly, You need to sort your data by name. let data = rawData.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name, 'es', { sensitivity: 'base' })).reduce(...

Comment: on typescript i'm getting `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.ts(7053)` for `r[group]`

Answer (score 0):

The `rawdata` should constitute the primary information deserving your attention. There's no need to generate the artificial object  labeled `data`. If your goal is to categorize objects based on the initial letter of their `name` property, all that's required is a representation function `repr` and a `TrueSet`.

```
import { TrueSet } from "@ut8pia/classifier/queue/TrueSet.js";
import { ORDER } from "@ut8pia/classifier/global.js"; 

const 
    repr = obj => obj.name[0],
    set = TrueSet.of(repr, ORDER.ASCENDING, ORDER.INSERTION)
        .letAll(rawdata);
```

Nothing else is needed. Your objects have been sorted and categorized.

You can verify this by:

```
const 
    rawdata = [
        { name : 'Baggage', id : 12 },
        { name : 'Animals', id : 10},
        { name : 'Batteries', id : 7},
        { name : 'Cake', id : 7}
    ],

    expected = [
        { name : 'Animals', id : 10},
        { name : 'Baggage', id : 12 },
        { name : 'Batteries', id : 7},
        { name : 'Cake', id : 7}
    ];

assert.deepEqual(set.toArray().map(obj => obj.name), expected.map(obj => obj.name));
```

To iterate over all the objects whose `name` starts with 'B':

```
const 
    allBs = set.class('B');

assert.deepEqual(allBs.toArray().map(obj => obj.name), expected.slice(1, 3).map(obj => obj.name))
```

However, I would recommend taking a step further by reconsidering the approach: why are you categorizing your objects based on the first letter of their names? Does the business logic of your computation demand it? Or is it a compromise due to programming complexities in achieving a better categorization? The `TrueSet` offers liberation from both contrived data structures and artificial categorizations as well.

You could utilize all the characters within the name to categorize your objects and employ one or more of these characters as `keys` to retrieve all the objects that share them. For example, consider utilizing the character 'a' located in the second position of the name.

```
const 
    repr = obj => [...obj.name],
    set = new TrueSet(repr)
        .letAll(rawdata),
    allAs = set.class(undefined, 'a');    

assert.deepEqual(allAs.toArray().map(obj => obj.name), expected.slice(1). map(obj => obj.name))
```

Answer (score -1):

in answer to @hakkikonu, for typescript add the type of outputed reducer when calling .reduce

```
 let data = rawData.reduce((r: any, e) => {
  let group = e.name[0];
  if (!r[group]) r[group] = { group, children: [e] }
  else r[group].children.push(e);
  return r;
}, {} );
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).